# How to assign value to dropdown for viewbag element?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I am developing MCV app with Razor syntax.
I have pass the elements to the dropdown list and I want to show selected item in that dropdown from viewbag element.

below code displays the dropdow code.

> Controller Code

```
      [SessionFilterAction]
            public ViewResult Details(int id)
    {

 ViewBag.HODList = new SelectList(db.Employees.Where(e => e.DesignationType == "HOD"), "Id", "FullName");
            ViewBag.ItemToBeSelectedInList = 5;
            return View(paymentadvice);
    }
```

> View Code

```
if(ViewBag.DesignationTypeOfLoggedUser == "Staff")
{
    @Html.DropDownList("HODList", String.Empty ,new { ???? })
}
```

Now I want to use viewbag element which will be select the one of the item of dropdown.
How to do this ?

Comment: You'd better use view models.

Answer (score 1):

ViewBag is designed to pass data from the controller to the view not to the other way. 
You can use HTTP Get method for populating drop down like

```
[HttpGet]
public MyAction()
{
    MyModel model = new MyModel();
```

// model.DropDwonValues is generic list class in model

```
    model.DropDwonValues= db.Values //replace with your db table
        .Select(v => new DropDownItem
            {
                Text = v.Name //value to go in your text field
                Value = v.Id.ToString() //value to go in your ID field
            })
        .ToList();   

    return View(model);
}
```

Then in your view you can do:

```
@using(Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.DropDownId)
    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.DropDownId , Model.DropDwonValues )
}
```

Comment: I am doing the same...I am trying to pass the data from the controller to view...you might read something wrong...

Comment: While the OP might indeed have misunderstood that you are trying to pass data from controller to the view he suggested the best practice here which is to use a view model and a strongly typed view instead of `ViewBag`. +1 from me.

Comment: I just want to pass the single variable to view... and want to set the item of dropdownlist according to that passed variable.

Comment: Hello...There is no way to assign the variable to dropdown ?